# Create windows executable using python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, ubuntu-14.04

python setup.py bdist_windist

Error:

```
Warning: Can't read registry to find the necessary compiler setting
Make sure that Python modules _winreg, win32api or win32con are installed.   
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe', /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe not included in the Debian packages.
```

Solution from this [page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1081155):

```
We cannot include the .exe files, because these are not built from source. Hint: copy these from the source package.
```

But where can i found those exes to copy.

Answer (score -2):

You can not create a Windows .exe on Debian/Linux.  You need to have a Windows Machine with a Python installation or a VM.

Comment: but setuptools doc says its possible. Line "These installers can even be created on Unix platforms or Mac OS X" from https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html

Comment: This used to work.  Precise (12.04) included the necessary wininst-6.0.exe file; see http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/amd64/python2.7-dev/filelist.  But it's gone from Trusty (14.04).  Why?  This makes it impossible to build Windows exe packages.

Comment: I managed to make it work by copying `wininst-*.exe` from a Windows machine with distutils (from `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\wininst-*.exe`) to the corresponding dir on the Linux side, and then it seems to be able to build the `.win32.exe`.